# handle a list of checkboxs and select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to show a list of items that these items is taken from database.(using a while in the php).

after click on a button, I would like to get where any checkboxs is selected and the value of it.
example :

[image]

I want to get:

item-1 => no

item-3 => yes

```
<div class="container">
    <select name="selectionField"> 
    <option value="CA" >yes</option>
    <option value="CO" >no</option>
    </select>
    <label for="blah">item-1</label> <input id="blah" type="checkbox" />

     <br />

    <select name="selectionField"> 
    <option value="CA" >yes</option>
    <option value="CO" >no</option>
    </select>
    <label for="blah">item-3</label> <input id="blah" type="checkbox" />

     <br />

    <select name="selectionField"> 
    <option value="CA" >yes</option>
    <option value="CO" >no</option>
    </select>
    <label for="blah">item-3</label> <input id="blah" type="checkbox" />

     <br />

</div>
```

Comment: Care to share what you have tried with us?

Comment: I am an android programmer and I have not enough knowledge about java script or ..

Answer (score 1):

With PHP, once the form is submitted you can get the values with:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
   print_r($_POST); //print all checked elements
}
```

With jQuery you can get the state with:

```
$("#blah").is(':checked');
```

Make sure you have unique ID's for each field